# Is there a way I can check when a player last joined a Minecraft server and their balance, by running a command with a discord bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js, minecraft

I was thinking this could be done with the paper/spigot API, but found no way of doing so. I have a bot and everything I just need to find some sort of link that can do this. -Thanks

Another solution I found could be rcon but I have NO experience with it.

Preferably this could be done with discord.js/javascript, but if needed I can use java.

PaperLIB on Github: https://github.com/PaperMC/PaperLib

There is also this API but I don't know if this can be used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-util

Comment: did you have a api to export those data from Minecraft server and test it with postman or browser or everything is just thinking

Comment: PaperLib doesn't appear to be useful in this situation.

Comment: @HellCatVN I don't exact know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at making a web API in Minecraft using `Vault` and `HTTPserver` or by using `JDA`. If you make the discord bot within the Minecraft Plugin then it's easier to link up but however if you are stronger in another language then you can look at HTTP server. You have a look at [this](https://github.com/FluxedScript/SmartStaff/tree/master/src/main/java/tk/ifutureserver/fluxedscript/smartstaff/webpanel) example for getting the details of a user in Java.

Comment: This Vault? https://www.vaultproject.io/api @FluxedScript

Comment: @Poetic the link provided by me shows an example of how to use it. Spigot's vault is located here: https://github.com/MilkBowl/VaultAPI

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered looking into Discord SRV(https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/discordsrv.18494/) It would probably be able to do most, if not all of what you are trying to do and save you a lot of time in my opinion. I would likely use the "remote console feature". However this does require a plugin on the server, so, obviously you will need to own the server!

Comment: Yes, I currently use DiscordSRV, its is for linking console and mc chat to a channel on discord. It doesn't have integration with bot commands, and doesn't fit what I am trying to do. Thanks though! I might look into a way to potentially use it.